# Getting "TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string" on some files

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-scripts

I have a create-react-app with the default setting. With some of my tests, I'm getting

```
TypeError: Cannot convert a Symbol value to a string

      2 | import * as React from 'react';
      3 | 
    > 4 | import { SomeItem } from 'some-library';
        | ^

      at Object.get (node_modules/create-emotion-styled/dist/index.cjs.js:216:200)
          at Proxy.toString (<anonymous>)
          at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/__tests__/SampleComponent.test.tsx:4:1)
```

This is only happening on *some* of the files. This specific import `import { SomeItem } from 'some-library';` is in ALL of my test files, and yet some of them pass, and some of them throw this error.

This just happens for test; building and the dev-server work just fine.

I'm very confused since this is not a consistent error and so I don't know how to debug this.

**UPDATE**

Seems like the problem is with `react-scripts`; I downgraded to v3.0.0 and re-ran test (had to run it with `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` because of all the other modules that I have installed), and the tests passed without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so I can't ask you any questions before answering, sorry.

It looks like you're trying to use emotion.

In emotion v10 `create-emotion-styled` would not be supported, check out [this](https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/1064) issue and consider using [CacheProvider](https://codesandbox.io/s/8x51k1mp2l) instead.

Comment: Ya I know - I'm using v9 though

Comment: I'll start poking around and get back to you (it's 3am, might be a bit), hopefully someone answers before me!

Sorry for using an answer

Comment: Oh, did you sort it out?

Comment: No I have not :(

Comment: Are the same tests throwing the error or is it different each time?

Comment: It's the same files - but if I were to delete those test files, then new files that were previously passing start to throw error